# matplotlib.pyplot.imshow() shows blank canvas

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I've come across an oddity that the internet hasn't been able to solve so far. If I read in a .png file, then try to show it, it works perfectly (in the example below the file is a single blue pixel). However, if I try to create this image array manually, it just shows a blank canvas. Any thoughts?

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('dot.png') # A single blue pixel
im1 = np.asarray(im)
print im1
# [[[  0 162 232 255]]]

plt.imshow(im1, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show() # Works fine

npArray = np.array([[[0, 162, 232, 255]]])
plt.imshow(npArray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show() # Blank canvas

npArray = np.array([np.array([np.array([0, 162, 232, 255])])])
plt.imshow(npArray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show() # Blank canvas
```

P.S. I've also tried replacing all of the np.array() with np.asarray(), but the outcome is just the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the `im.show` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

```
X : array_like, shape (n, m) or (n, m, 3) or (n, m, 4)
    Display the image in `X` to current axes.  `X` may be a float
    array, a uint8 array or a PIL image.
```

So `X` may be an array with dtype `uint8`.

When you don't specify a dtype,

```
In [63]: np.array([[[0, 162, 232, 255]]]).dtype
Out[63]: dtype('int64')
```

NumPy may create an array of dtype `int64` or `int32` (*not* `uint8`) by default.

---

If you specify `dtype='uint8'` explicitly, then

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

npArray = np.array([[[0, 162, 232, 255]]], dtype='uint8')
plt.imshow(npArray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

---

PS. If you check

```
im = Image.open('dot.png') # A single blue pixel
im1 = np.asarray(im)
print(im1.dtype)
```

you'll find `im1.dtype` is `uint8` too.

Comment: Solved :D Thanks for the insanely quick reply too :P

Comment: u r genius.. OP solution 